# Add background image to Android Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

How can I add image to Android Toolbar in Android Studio?

Comment: yes its possible

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836497/common-background-image-for-actionbar-toolbar-and-statusbar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Add an ImageView inside your toolbar in xml file.You can also try using a RelativeLayout with the Toolbar overlaying an ImageView.