# How to draw layout with views under system bars?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have to make layout, where top of the layout should be drawn under `SystemBars`. **(min API level for this app is 22)**

I set these flags to achieve that. In other activities I can draw whole fragment with views under `SystemBars`, but here I cant do it.

I used this code to allow layout to be drawn under `SystemBars`

```
window.apply {
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        statusBarColor = resources.getColor(android.R.color.transparent)
        navigationBarColor = resources.getColor(android.R.color.transparent)
        setBackgroundDrawable(background)
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    }
```

This is result in app:

[image]

I need to draw that grey area under system bar.

**Update:**

**@Redman** solution worked only partially.
Now I can draw under `StatusBar` but also I can draw under software buttons (`navigationButtons`) as you can see at screen below. Is there any way how to allow layout to be drawn under `SystemBars` but do not allow it under `navigationButtons`? Because that code what I've posted works for different fragments in app. But in other fragments I don't have `ImageView` as a part of `ToolBar`. If you have just `ToolBar` with for example 2-color gradient background and some `backButton` + `SearchView`, it is working fine. But as I add `ImageView`, `ImageView` will not "slide" under top `SystemBar(aka StatusBar)`. Even in image above you can clearly see that green color (it's ToolBar background drawn under `StatusBar`). But `ImageView` is not allowed to be drawn under that bar.

The only way how to achieve that was with that special line of code

```
window.apply { 
        setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

    }
```

but this line also allowed to draw layout content under `NavigationButtons` (which is an issue).

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836497/common-background-image-for-actionbar-toolbar-and-statusbar/45836597#45836597

Comment: Do you mean **behind** the notification bar?

Comment: Yes behind. Will fix that

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity` Theme add these properties

```
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

and in parent layout add property

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

**Edit**

Try this to do it programmatically, it should work above on devices having kitkat and above

```
    window.apply { 
        setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
    }
```

Comment: <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item> 

I cant add this to style. It will make my system Bar darker. I need it fully transparent. What I will add to parent layout background, it should be background of systembar aswell. And fitsSystemWindows="true" will make whole layout to fit bottom system bar buttons (if you have software buttons). And those buttons will be covered by my layout.

Comment: This is working properly for status bar but navigation bar is broken. If you have software buttons at the bottom of the screen, my whole layout is drawn over those buttons. I want to keep buttons intact and layout should be drawn over status bar only.

Answer (score 1):

use toolbar view in your xml file. See below example

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_50dp"
            android:background="#f1f1f1">

\\define your any element here. Like back arrow or title

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: whole header is located inside toolbar layout. Inside toolbar layout is CoordinatorLayout with imageViews and TextViews + buttons.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set these properties in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Your activity / container layout you wish to have a transparent status bar needs this property set:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

It is generally not possible to perform this for sure on pre-kitkat, looks like you can do it but some strange code makes it so.

**EDIT:** I would recommend this lib: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint for lots of pre-lollipop status bar color control.

Well after much deliberation I've learned that the answer to totally disabling the translucency or any color placed on the status bar and navigation bar for lollipop is to set this flag on the window:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Window window = getWindow();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_dark));
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
        window.addFlags(flags);
    }
```

This should make Only StatusBar transparent.

---

If this didn't help, try adding:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

To the `Activity` styles code in `styles.xml`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Same result as other solutions here

Comment: What about now? I've used `setStatusBarColor` for the statusbar..It should help now

Comment: If i use only your code it will not draw toolbar under statusBar. As i add *setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)* it will draw content under statusBar but also under navigationBar

Comment: So in this case, I believe adding `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` to styles will help.