# BottomNavigationBar underneath NavBar

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, navbar, bottomnavigationview

**The Goal**:

1) Make the status bar transparent - **Done**

2) Make the `BottomNavigationView` and the `Navbar` the same color. - **Almost Done**

**The Problem**

By adding the following code in my `Activity`, the status bar becomes transparent. BUT, `BottomNavigationView` falls underneath the `NavBar`. If I remove this line of code, the `StatusBar` no longer is transparent. You feel my pain here? Furthermore... How would I make the **TOP** of the layout go underneath the statusbar?

**The Code in the Activity:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

**The Activity XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<com.custom.app.view.ClickableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tab_layout" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/custom_black"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The Style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/md_white_1000</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/custom_black</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/custom_black</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AppTheme.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/md_white_1000</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/custom_black</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347297/can-i-set-flag-layout-no-limits-only-for-status-bar

Answer (score 8):

> BottomNavigationBar underneath NavBar

The reason your **`BottomNavigationView`** hiding behind **`NavBar`** because your are setting this flags

```
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

SEE the result using that flags

[image]

**SIMPLE SOLUTION**

To make your `statusbar` transparent just use **`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>`**

and use below flags

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
 getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

> Root layout

You need to use   **`android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`** as your  `rootlayout`

> CartActivity

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);


    }

}
```

> layout.activity_cart

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#199bd2"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#000"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> CustAppTheme2

```
<style name="CustAppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000</item>

</style>
```

> Finally OUTPUT

[image]

> Finally OUTPUT on kitkat

[image]

Comment: I've tried exactly as you've recommended but the top status bar is grey'ish instead of transparent.

Comment: @Subby make `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` your `rootlayout `

Comment: it doesn't work for me .... I've done all you said , this is my root  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000">

Comment: @NavidAbutorab have you tried using `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);`

Answer (score 2):

> How would I make the TOP of the layout go underneath the statusbar?

Add this to root layout of each activity you need:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

> BottomNavigationView falls underneath the NavBar

I don't know if you can find a way to handle this as long as you keep using `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`. If you still want to use it, you may try to check if device has a `NavigationBar` and calculate its height which you can give to `BottomNavigationView` as a bottom margin.

To do that you can find some useful methods in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609679/10327883).
Add another method like:

```
public void setMargin(int height){
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mBottomNavigationView.getLayoutParams();
    params.bottomMargin = height;
}
```

And in `onCreate()`, get the height of the `NavigationBar` if it exists and `setMargin` of `BottomNavigationView`:

```
int bottomNavHeight = getNavigationBarSize(this).y;
if( bottomNavHeight > 0){
         setMargin(bottomNavHeight);
}
```

Result will be like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code but, most probably it should work

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, false);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

The code you have added allows the window to extend outside the actual output area.So. most probably that is allowing your activity to come beneath system  widgets that is status bar and nav bar and giving them a transparent look.

Try to remove the code you mentioned from java activity and replace it with mine. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case this may help somebody: I had this problem for almost a year, and solved it by using both

1. CoordinatorLayout for the root layout
2. ConstraintLayout for the fragment in which I had the bottom bar.
3. Of course I added android:fitsSystemWindows="true" as mentioned
   above.

So you may want to try **constraintLayout** if the other solutions don't work.