# How to stretch layout background image all the way up to status bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have followed may solutions but none of them works . I wan to know the easiest way to achieve this...(Background images covers the status bar)

[image]

Comment: Try this answer it will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294746/bottomnavigationbar-underneath-navbar/52341684#52341684

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please these to your Base Application theme style

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

You also need to add below property to your parent layout.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```